Ngx Translate Routes returns TypeError: translatedPaths.findIndex is not a function
After update Angular project from v13 to v18 I started recive error with path translation.
This occurs for example when I click on link in navbar menu. Error looks like:
header.component.html:93  Error translating route: TypeError: translatedPaths.findIndex is not a function
    at #updateLocationIfChanged (ngx-translate-routes.mjs:127:39)
    at ngx-translate-routes.mjs:85:42
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:17:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:369:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:7219:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:34)
    at ZoneImpl.run (zone.js:111:43)
    at zone.js:2538:40

What is more strange, the same project downloaded on different computer works correctly.
I've tried uninstall package ngx-translate-routes and install one more time.
I've also tried delete whole node_modules folder and run npm install from scratch.
I even compared whole package's documentation with my project and everything looks good.
Any sugestions?

node version same?

node version has changed from v14 to v20

Changing the Node version to 18.20 (the last one compatible with Angular v18) did not help.

The problem is with web browser. It doesn't work on Edge, but on Chrome it works perfectly.
